# How to pipe two commands as parameters?

Tags: bash, diff, pipe

Is it possible to pipe two commands as arguments/parameters to a command-line-program?

I am using the program combinediff to merge diffs together like:

```
combinediff patchfile1 patchfile2
```

which is working fine, but I would like to avoid having to save the diffs into files in the first place. Passing one pipe works fine (for example out of mercurial) but using two does not work. Is something like this possible?:

```
combinediff | hg diff 1234 | hg diff 1337
```

It does work with one pipe so far but the second gets ignored.

Comment: You have already got a -1 for this question, which is an indication, you could have made a good search, before asking such question..
A good search on stackoverflow itself would have come handy.

Comment: Your concept of pipes seems to involve a fair amount of magic. `a | b` really is nothing more than `a>file; b<file` only without the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash has process substitution.

```
combinediff <(hg diff 1234) <(hg diff 1337)
```

This is not available in traditional Bourne shell; the workaround is to use a temporary file for one of the inputs.

```
tmp=$(mktemp -t combine.XXXXXXX) || fail loudly
trap 'rm $tmp' EXIT
trap 'exit 127' TERM INT
hg diff 1234 >$tmp
hg diff 1337 | combinediff $tmp -
```

(This presupposes that `combinediff` understands `-` as standard input. If you have `/dev/fd/0` then you can use that just as if it were a regular file, but again, it's also not portable back to jurassic Unix. In the worst case, use two temporary files.)